# Why the program stuck at the await statement if using while loop and using lock.locked() checking

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I am writing a code to simulate getting data from a website which takes 3-5seconds with multiple selenium drivers but I cannot even get one browser working. I want to implement while loop inside an async function but the program seems stuck at the await `asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(3, 5))` statement so the lock is never released so other async basically cannot enter the `async with lock_browser`:

```
import asyncio
import random
import time

async def work(lock_browser,x,y):     
  while True:
    if lock_browser.locked() is False:
      async with lock_browser: 

        await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(3, 5)) #simulate only one browser connect to the website at a time

        print(x,y)
        break
    
async def main(x):
    tasks=[]
    lock_browser = asyncio.Lock()
    for y in range(5):
        tasks.append(work(lock_browser, x,y))    
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)  

if __name__ == "__main__":
  start = time.perf_counter()
  for x in range(5):
    asyncio.run(main(x))


  end = time.perf_counter()
  duration=end-start
  print(f'Time elapsed:{duration:.2f}s')
```

The program will run if I remove the while & break statement. What are the possible causes that the program stuck inside the `work()` function??

Comment: The while never gives control back to the event loop of the lock isn’t available. You need at least a sleep(0) in the hypothetical else part.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi this solved my issue, but why do I need to add the async sleep in the else part, I mean what is the effect to the way it runs? Do I basically need to add sleep in every if statement in while loop inside an aync function?